# What's wrong with this regular expression to find URLs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a JavaScript to extract a URL from a Google search URL, like so:

```
http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=thisisthepartiwanttofind.org&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8
```

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
var checkForURL = /[\w\d](.org)/i;
var findTheURL = checkForURL.exec(theURL);
```

I've ran this through a couple regex testers and it seems to work, but in practice the string I get returned looks like this:

```
thisisthepartiwanttofind.org,.org
```

So where's that trailing `,.org` coming from?

I know my pattern isn't super robust but please don't suggest better patterns to use. I'd really just like advice on what in particular I did wrong with this one. Thanks!

Comment: `[\w\d]` doesn't make sense. it only matches one character (letter, number, or underscore)

Comment: You're right! I left out the trailing `+`.

Comment: Also, `[\w\d]` is exactly the same as `\w`.  `\w` already matches digits, so the `\d` is redundant.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I thought it did, but then I started second-guessing myself so I didn't say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses in the regex if you do not process the `.org` (unlikely since it is a literal). As per @Mark comment, add a `+` to match one or more characters of the class `[\w\d]`. Also, I would escape the dot:

```
var checkForURL = /[\w\d]+\.org/i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `.`(DOT) in `(.org)` regex group or it matches any character. So your regex would become:

```
/[\w\d]+(\.org)/
```

---

To match the url in your example you can use something like [this](http://regexr.com?31o67):

```
https?://([0-9a-zA-Z_.?=&\-]+/?)+
```

or something more accurate like [this](http://regexr.com?31o6a) (you should choose the right regex according to your needs):

```
^https?://([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+\.)+(com|org|net|WhatEverYouWant)(/[0-9a-zA-Z_\-?=&.]+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually getting is an array of 2 results, the first being the whole match, the second - the group you defined by using parens (.org).

Compare with:

```
/([\w\d]+)\.org/.exec('thisistheurl.org')
→ ["thisistheurl.org", "thisistheurl"]

/[\w\d]+\.org/.exec('thisistheurl.org')
→ ["thisistheurl.org"]

/([\w\d]+)(\.org)/.exec('thisistheurl.org')
→ ["thisistheurl.org", "thisistheurl", ".org"]
```

The result of an .exec of a JS regex is an Array of strings, the first being the whole match and the subsequent representing groups that you defined by using parens. If there are no parens in the regex, there will only be one element in this array - the whole match.